# How can I tell when android AudioRecord read() method encounters an overflow?

Tags: android, buffer-overflow, audiorecord

I am using android.media.AudioRecord to get raw audio input, and then I am processing this in real-time to display immediate feedback.  I can adjust various processing parameters to change the quality of the feedback, with a corresponding change in processing time.

As I increase processing time, at some point AudioRecord starts to overflow and read() starts missing chunks of data. Besides a noticable change in the display, I get the following message in LogCat (I am using eclipse to debug):
"E/AudioHardwareYamaha(2579): snd_pcm_readi read error -32"

How can my app find out about this error? It is not good enough to find out while debugging, I want the app to know when this happens so it can automatically adjust the parameters, to find a sweet spot where the quality is as high as possible but the overflows are gone or infrequent. I assume this sweet spot will be different on different hardware.

I have checked here and elsewhere, but the suggestions I have found fall short:

- Increasing the buffer size beyond some small multiple is not a solution, as it only defers an inevitable glitch (and adds latency to the feedback).
- I have seen a suggestion for putting reading and processing in separate threads. Basically this amounts to a wrapper for AudioRecord, adding a good deal of complexity and even more processing, just to do my own error detection. My app is basically done, and I don't really want to refactor everything if I can avoid it.
- Checking elapsed times against what is expected seems to be the most workable solution at this time, but it seems bizarre that I have to settle on such an indirect strategy to guess at what AudioRecord has done (and logged).

Is there a simple way for an app to capture the error information that is being logged?

Comment: What feedback are you trying to display?  I would think that keeping the recording and processing off the main (UI) thread is what you should be doing anyway.

Comment: I want to show the chord being played, as it is being played.  The UI is in a separate thread, the recording (ie, reading) and processing are together in another thread.

Comment: Have you found out exactly what would cause the `-32` `snd_cpm_readi` error?

Comment: Just that it occurs when read()s don't happen often enough. I know this indirectly, but I can't find any documentation.

Comment: I should add that I have a strategy to smooth over gaps in the input if I know about them soon enough. Thus, using the clock gives me a general idea of when I need to cut back on processing quality, but this info is too imprecise to fix a gap.

Comment: 'snd_pcm_readi` is a function in the `Alsa` open source C code. Have you tried making the `AudioRecord` buffer bigger?  If that doesn't work, you will have to split the recording and processing, so that you can empty the buffer given to `AudioRecord` into another that processing accesses.  I don't know if you can hook the driver functions but that would be even more complicated than having an extra thread.

Comment: Hi Dave, did you manage to resolve this issue? I am seeing an "AudioHardwareYamaha: resampler read error -32", which may be related. (This occurs on SGS2, 4.1.2. Didn't happen on 2.3.4, or at least not as frequently.)

Comment: I have not resolved this issue. First, making the buffer bigger does not solve my problem - I know I can not make the error go away, I just want my program to know when it happens. Second, if by "I am seeing..." you mean you see it in the console - I too am seeing the errors just fine, but my program is not.

Comment: @DaveWalley please stop, I understand your frustration but as a community member we need rollback it all. Take the day off, then tomorrow clean up some more, don't leave protests all over SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question in case someone stumbles on this...

I was not able to find a good solution, but I have been using a work-around.  I ended up using the clock, rather than the audio input hardware.  Since I know how big my input buffer is, and I know how many input samples are made per second, and I can find how fast my code is running from the system clock, I can calculate when an overflow SHOULD occur, and write my code around that.

Not exactly what I was hoping for, but it accomplished what I needed.